# Loop each array element in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking for a way to read each line of a text document as an array element.

```
<?php

$file = fopen("nums.txt", "r");
$i = 0;
$line = "";
$access_key = '1234567890';
while (!feof($file)) {
     $line .= fgets($file);
}
$numbers = explode("\n", $line);

for ($i=0; $i < count($numbers); $i++) { 
    $ch = curl_init('http://apilayer.net/api/validate?access_key='.$access_key.'&number='.$numbers[$i].'');  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $json = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $validationResult = json_decode($json, true);
    echo $numbers[$i] . '</span>' . $validationResult['valid'] . ' ' . $validationResult['country_code'] . ' ' . $validationResult['carrier'];
}

fclose($file);


?>
```

Any tips are appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Any errors, problems, unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Yea the thing is it should send thru the api each document line individually, but it just keeps sending the whole document:( sad panda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$numbers = explode(PHP_EOL, $line);
```

Is this what you wanted?

Updated with PHP_EOL

Comment: You guys are great, so simple solution Cheers!

Comment: This works ONLY because the file and the OS (windows) `PHP_EOL` have the same end of line `\r\n`.  If you move the script to Linux you'll have the same problem again because `PHP_EOL` will only be `\n`.  When you know the line ending don't use `PHP_EOL`.

Answer (score 1):

You could save a lot of work.  Read into an array and trim the `\n` and/or `\r` and `foreach()`:

```
$numbers = array_map('trim', file('nums.txt'));

foreach($numbers as $number) {
    // echo $number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the file content by path.
$file = file_get_contents($file);
// Break the file into array of lines.
$lines = preg_split('/\r*\n+|\r+/', $file);
// Remove last element as the last \r\n adds an extra element into the array.
array_pop($lines);

// Iterate over each line.
foreach($lines as $line_number => $line_content){

  // do something...
}
```